# React Library Using Webpack + TS + Material Ui

Tags: typescript, material-ui, webpack-5

Creating a custom component library using react + typescript + webpack

Facing an issue when used components other than react

invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

And also some times throws like

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
useContext
/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618

Tried changing versions of react and other dependencies

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "material-avatar": "^0.3.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-script": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "*"
  },
  "files": [
    "./dist"
  ]
}
```

.tsx file

```
import React from "react";
import  Button  from '@mui/material/Button';

interface ButtonProps {
    items: itemsArrayInterface[];
    title: String
}

 interface itemsArrayInterface {
     id: Number,
     addedBy: String,
     page: String,
     likes: String,
     unLikes: String,
     adminApproved: String,
     comments: String,
     time: string,
     rating: Number
   }

export default function(props : ButtonProps){
 
    return (
        <>
        <Button>hello</Button>
        </>
    )
   
}
```

webpack config

```js
const path = require("path");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    mode: "production",
    target: "node",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "index.js",
        libraryTarget: "umd",
        library: "library",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                        options: {
                            compilerOptions: {
                                noEmit: false,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },

    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".d.ts"],
    },
};
```

ts config

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es6", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ], /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "jsx": "react", /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */
    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",                       /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */
    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true, /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true, /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    "noImplicitThis": true, /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give us specific code that causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Your using react hooks against rule of Hooks.
please check react hooks usage rule your problem will be solved.
[react hooks Usage Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)
or please update your question and add code how you use react hooks.